# French mother gave me up for adoption

Tags: eu-citizens

My mother was a French citizen. I was born in Casablanca and given for adoption to a US couple there on the Air Base. I just learned this. If I can locate my birth record and it is connected to my French passport number as an infant, am I considered a French citizen?

Comment: Your French passport number, if any, is likely irrelevant.  The fact that you were born of a French mother is probably relevant.  The year of your birth is probably also significant; I don't know much about French nationality law, but in most countries laws have changed over time and the law in effect at the time of your birth controls.  An example of changing laws: in many countries, the rules used to depend on whether the mother was married at the time of birth, but more an more countries are abandoning that.

Comment: You'll certainly want to investigate whether the adoption would have terminated your French nationality before spending time and money establishing the facts surrounding your birth to see whether you had it in the first place.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_nationality_law), `The child (legitimate or natural) is French if at least one parent is French. In the case of an adoption, the child has French nationality only under the "full adoption" regime. Parentage to the parent from whom the French nationality is claimed, must be established while the child is still a minor (under 18).'

Comment: @Tomas By: I'm pretty sure the latter sentences handle the opposite case, French citizens adopting a non-french child.

Comment: @Janka: #2 probably, but #3 sounds like biological parent French, which is how I understand the present case.